# More efficient method to color substring of text?

Tags: java, android, android-view

I have an array of strings that is programatically created. The String array is used by an `ArrayAdapter` and then attached to a `ListView`. My end goal is to change the color of a substring in each of the strings. I am currently achieving this by overriding `getView()` of the `ArrayAdapter`, and then using `SpannableStrings` to format the substring.

I was curious if there was a more efficient way to do this. If my understanding is correct, `getView()` is constantly being called whenever the user scrolls, so it seems really inefficient to me to be doing all of this text processing when scrolling.

I have tried overriding the Adapter to accept a list of `SpannableStrings` and then making the color changes when I am constructing the list of `SpannableStrings`, but when I actually set the adapter using the list, the colors do not persist.

Perhaps I am already doing it the best way, but I figured I might as well ask since scrolling is a big part of the user experience and I want it to be as smooth as possible.

Comment: For example I use someView.setText(Html.fromHtml(display_name), 
TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE); - works very well for me even with fast scroll. But you have to pre-build the html string.

Comment: The display name looks something like "Jo<font color='red'>hn</font>" - with 'hn' highlighted in red